# Displaying Number of Found Posts on Results Page in WordPress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, search, themes

I want to display the total number of found posts on results page in WordPress. For example "If someone searches for 'cat' it should display count for posts with the term 'cat', Right now I inserted some PHP code but it is displaying the total number of published posts and that's not I want to achieve. Please follow this link: https://bigfunx.com/?s=cats&id=1516&post_type=post
And you will clearly see that there are four articles found for cat and it is displaying 28 as count instead of 4. I hope you are understanding what I am trying to achieve. Looking forward to hearing from you soon. Thank you!

I try to enter the following code:

```
<?php $args = array(
'post_type' => 'post'
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
$totalposts = $query->found_posts;
if($totalposts < 2) {
$result = "Meme";
} else {
$result = "Memes";
}
echo $totalposts . " " . $result; ?>
```

The above code is displaying the total number of published posts and also with singular and plural feature but I know I am missing something to properly displaying the result, Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You want to use https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_n/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you add that code, but you can try this:

`$args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 's' => isset( $_GET['s'] ) ? $_GET['s'] : '')`

Just add the 's' key in you $args variable.

This is not the best solution because you are making additional query on the search page. But given the info you have in your question that should work.

Better solution would be in the page where you display the title (search page) you can try:

`global $wp_query; $totalposts = $wp_query->found_posts;`

Comment: Your provided code only displays "1" and "0" count, If I searched any query and search returned some posts then it outputs "1" and if search didn't returned any post then it outputs "0" as count. Still didn't outputs the exact number of posts that are displaying on results page. Sometimes it outputs "0" even if some posts are displaying. There is something to do with the array I guess but I don't know how?

Comment: I also tried the code that you provided at the end of your answer, It always outputs "0" There should be some workaround for this to work.

Comment: I write the PHP code in PHP snippets plugin and inserted that PHP code in query loop section of the search template via WordPress shortcode block.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, use th `_n()` to pluralize your string.

```
<?php
$args       = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
);
$query      = new WP_Query( $args );
$totalposts = $query->found_posts;
echo esc_attr( $totalposts . ' ' . _n( 'Meme', 'Memes', $totalposts ) );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, This is a neat trick to display singular and plural but this is not what I want to achieve. I just want to display total number of posts for the entered query.